# Rigify leg/arm pole bone controls

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones, rigify

I have a quick question, how do i control pole bones using Rigify Control rig, or where do i find it. Is it because i didnt create a pole bone in the meta rig at the first place? I can find a pole bone in one of the armature layers, but those bones are constrained and probably aren't meant to be meddled with.

Comment: rigify should create the pole bone as part of creating the IK rig, but normally you don't want to control it; you just control the IK target.  What do you want to do with the pole?

Comment: I wanted to control how the leg would twist whilst crouching(like knees closer together or   farther). I just found i can rotate those red IK arrows to do just that. came here to delete my question and noticed someone already answered. 
Thank you for lightning fast response :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Rigify's rig does not use a pole target. It uses this arrow control which you have to **rotate**. That will affect the direction of the elbow

[image]

If you prefer the well-known pole target, you have to press the toggle pole button under Rig Main Properties. This has to be done for each limb individually. Legs work the same way.

[image]